# How to efficiently iterate table number in Selenium Webdriver using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Please suggest me how to changes efficiently tr[1], [2], [3] or N numbers, following the table provided on the website automatically

code :

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="event"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[9]').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="event"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[9]').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="event"]/tbody/tr[3]/td[9]').click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like below:

```
options = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="event"]/tbody/tr') # this xpath should highlight all the tr tags in the DOM

for opt in options:
    opt.find_element_by_xpath('./td[9]') # this should get the 9th td tag of that particular tr. Use a "." in the xpath to find element within an element.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using [`find_elements_by_xpath('.//tr')`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_xpath) instead of `find_element_by_xpath`.

Alternatively, you can use a simple for loop with a try-except. It's not the most elegant, but it will get you all N rows before going out due to the exception.